# Is there a way to avoid In-App (30%) fee for any purchases in iOS?

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, app-store, app-store-connect

I have an app which has some purchase option. However, I don't want to make it through the app itself. For that, I already have a website for the purchase.

So can I create a redirection page from my app to the respective webpage?

Will my app get rejected?

or is there a better solution?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not about programming

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want to sell tokens/credits/gold coins/gems or whatever as consumables in a game they also must be through In App Purchase. Meanwhile for Physical elements that we brought from any e commence app that must should go through your requirement.

hope this work 
for more info refer this link [blog post describing it](https://blog.tallwave.com/2016/04/13/in-app-purchases-what-you-need-to-know-before-developing-a-mobile-app)

Comment: Hi, Say I'm building a freelance platform like fiverr...so would i have to pay for every transaction i make thr?..if it's inside the app..for example say i hired somebody to edit a video for me and I payed him $200 for the work..so would I have to use the IAP or I can another payment processor such as stripe?

Comment: As ot states "for digital content consumed in the app" so, if the person i hired to edit the video sents it to me ON THE APP ITSELF... would it be considered in IAP?

Answer (score 4):

It depends on what you are selling, if you are offering "Physical Goods and Services Outside of the App" you cannot use IAP and must use something else as described in the [App Store Review Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/#physical-goods-and-services)

> 3.1.5 (a) Physical Goods and Services Outside of the App: If your app enables people to purchase goods or services that will be consumed outside of the app, you must use purchase methods other than in-app purchase to collect those payments, such as Apple Pay or traditional credit card entry.

If not then you must use IAP and will be charged a 30% fee. However, if you are offering subscriptions this rate will drop down to 15% for users who have been subscribed for over 1 year. Check out [Offering Subscriptions](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/subscriptions/) for more info if you are interested.

Answer (score 2):

There isn’t any,

According to Apple’s official guidelines

> If you want to unlock features or functionality within your app, (by way of example: subscriptions, in-game currencies, game levels, access to premium content, or unlocking a full version), you must use in-app purchase. Apps may use in-app purchase currencies to enable customers to “tip” digital content providers in the app. Apps and their metadata may not include buttons, external links, or other calls to action that direct customers to purchasing mechanisms other than in-app purchase.

You must use in-app purchases and Apple’s official API’s, if it’s not a physical item

Otherwise your app will be rejected

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, let me answer your question based on my experience(bad :( ) with Apple

```
So can I create a redirection page from my app to the respective webpage?  - NO

Will my app get rejected? - YES

or is there a better solution? - Depend on types of app.
```

The In-App guidelines are recently updated with few more changes so it's depends on what kind of feature you are subscribing. For example:

> 3.1.4 Hardware-Specific Content: In limited circumstances, such as when features are dependent upon specific hardware to function, the
>   app may unlock that functionality without using in-app purchase (e.g.
>   an astronomy app that adds features when synced with a telescope).

To be honest, **DON'T trust these exceptions** and build your app based on this. In our case, app works exclusively based on a connected physical device device. After rejection from Apple, we appealed with this exception but we didn't hear from Apple for more than a month..!

**Using subscription through website**

Many thinks that they can get away In-app purchase by offering subscription  through website and removing t from app. B**ut Apple will still reject your app and confirmed with Apple team.** If you are thinking about Spotify and Netflix cases, there is a category of apps it's only permitted called **"Reader app"**. Please refer 3.1.3(a) of Apple guidelines.