# i want to buy ebook in my app. can i make a payment through webview without using in app purchase.. is Itunes stores approved my app

Tags: ios, swift, iphone

i need to buy ebook in my app without using in-app purchase or Apple pay. I have a website to buy ebook. Can i using that webpage for purchase. is it possible in my iphone app?? Suppose if i using that webpage is apple will approve my app in store?

Comment: Have a look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48084081/4056108)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a way to avoid In-App (30%) fee for any purchases in iOS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48058415/is-there-a-way-to-avoid-in-app-30-fee-for-any-purchases-in-ios)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the Apple guidelines digital contents need to be purchased by In App Purchase.

Ebooks are digital content so you need to integrate In App Purchase. if you use Webpage then your app may get reject.